# How to run a script to remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, admin, remote-access

I've a machine and a remote machine.

Now I've a script which does some simple operations(basically execute 50 odd linux CLIs). 
This script is present **locally** on my machine and **NOT** on remote machine.

Is there a neat way which can let me run this local script run on remote machine?

Comment: copy it there and then execute

Comment: This has been already [answered several times](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of scp and ssh e.g.

```
scp myscript.sh auser@host:/home/auser/path \
&& ssh auser@host '/home/auser/path/myscript.sh'
```

Without copying you can directly execute it as

```
cat myscript.sh | xargs  -0 ssh auser@host
```

Or if you don't like pipes

```
xargs -a myscript.sh -0 ssh auser@host
```

Comment: I don''t want to do any write operation on remote machine by scp/copy. Any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

As answered here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments
you can just do

```
ssh auser@host "bash -s" < ./myscript.sh
```